# Before/After/Around for ScalaCheck?

Tags: scala, specs2, scalacheck

specs2 has traits such as `Before`, `After`, `Around`, etc. in order to be able to wrap examples in setup/teardown code.

Is there anything to support setting up and tearing down testing infrastructure for each "iteration" of a ScalaCheck property, i.e. each value or set of values to be tested by ScalaCheck?

It looks like specs2's various Before, After, Around traits are designed around returning or throwing specs2 Result instances, and a Prop isn't a Result.

Comment: The problem is, although there is an implicit conversion from `Prop` to `Result`, there isn't one going back the other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now in the latest 1.12.2-SNAPSHOT. You can now write:

```
import org.specs2.ScalaCheck
import org.specs2.mutable.{Around, Specification}
import org.specs2.execute.Result

class TestSpec extends Specification with ScalaCheck {
  "test" >> prop { i: Int =>
    around(i must be_>(1))
  }

  val around = new Around {
    def around[T <% Result](t: =>T) = {
      ("testing a new Int").pp
      try { t }
      finally { "done".pp }
    }
  }    
}
```

And this will execute code before and after the "body" of the Property.

You can also go a step further and create a support method to pass in an implicit `around` to your Props:

```
class TestSpec extends Specification with ScalaCheck {
  "test" >> propAround { i: Int =>
    i must be_>(1)
  }

  // use any implicit "Around" value in scope
  def propAround[T, R](f: T => R)
                      (implicit a: Around, 
                       arb: Arbitrary[T], shrink: Shrink[T], 
                       res: R => Result): Result =
    prop((t: T) => a(f(t)))

  implicit val around = new Around {
    def around[T <% Result](t: =>T) = {
      ("testing a new Int").pp
      try { t }
      finally { "done".pp }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But the first code sample you provided doesn't compile with the latest snapshot from sonatype. I tried compiling specs2 from git with `sbt`, but got `[error] {file:/home/robin/git/specs2/project/}plugins/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.jsuereth#xsbt-gpg-plugin;0.6: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: me.lessis#ls-sbt;0.1.2: not found`

Comment: By the way, I am using Scala 2.9.1 at the moment.

Comment: This kind of plugin issue is due to a Scala version mismatch indeed. You can just get rid of the plugins in the build files. Anyway I just published a 1.12.2-SNAPSHOT for Scala 2.9.1 so that you don't need to compile yourself.

Comment: Thanks again, Eric - the level of free support you're providing for specs2 is excellent!